# do numerical integration with fixed abscissas

Tags: integration, na.numerical-analysis

Can I do an integral, possibly using gaussian quadrature, when the abscissas are fixed (for reasons that I don't want to get into right now), i.e. is it possible to calculate the weights for fixed abscissas that I don't get to choose?

Comment: Please see http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask - I'm not sure what to make of this question.

Comment: Sorry if the question is not clear enough. Gaussian quadrature uses a set of polynomials, whose roots become the abscissas and then has a prescription for finding the weight for each abscissa. In my case I do not know the polynomials, only the abscissas beforehand, and would like to find the weights. Thanks.

Comment: Question has also been posted to m.se, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55687/do-numerical-integration-with-fixed-abscissas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation of the problem: given $n$ pairs $(x_j, f(x_j)$ with 
$a \le x_1 < x_2 < \ldots < x_n \le b$, you want an approximation 
to $\int_a^b f(x)\, dx$.

One way, that would give the correct value for polynomials
of degree $\le n-1$, would be to use $\int_a^b g(x)\, dx$ where $g$ is the Lagrange interpolating polynomial of degree $\le n-1$ corresponding to your data.  However, that
can be very unstable (see "Runge's phenonenon").  A better idea might be to use something like a composite quadrature rule: partition your interval into subintervals, each containing a few of the $x_j$, and use the interpolation for those $x_j$ in the subinterval to approximate the integral over that subinterval.

Comment: @Robert Israel: the problem I was trying to solve is precisely as you stated it. Thanks for the answer. So, essentially, many small-power polynomials are better than one large-power polynomial. What I plan to do is use the algorithm J.M. mentioned in each subinterval.

Comment: @jackj: Right, so probably we could give better suggestions if you'd mention what those "fixed abscissas" look like...

Comment: @J. M. : sorry for the long delay in responding. My abscissas look like $\delta\sqrt{a+n^2}$ where $a$ is "small" and $n$ is an integer.

Comment: You might map these to uniformly spaced abscissas by the transformation $t = \sqrt{x^2/\delta^2 - a}$.

Answer (score 1):

You could fit a cubic spline through the given data points, and then integrate the cubics exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I have settled this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55687/55742#55742); in brief, a [FORTRAN implementation](http://www.netlib.org/toms/655) of algorithms for solving this problem have been published in the Collected Algorithms of the ACM.

---

At the risk of being redundant, I'd like to mention here some other things I mentioned in the (now expanded) answer of mine at that other site for completeness' sake.

Robert's warning of the Runge phenomenon happening is a good one, and it does happen if your abscissas are perversely distributed (relatedly, the underlying Vandermonde matrix is ill-conditioned); the equispaced case being among the worst-behaved point distributions. Abscissas that are "nicely distributed" (e.g. Legendre, Chebyshev, or any other point distribution which "clusters" near the ends) will generally ensure that you have a quadrature rule that behaves tamely even for large numbers of points. (As an aside, the [`chebfun` project](http://www2.maths.ox.ac.uk/chebfun/) hinges on functions being nicely approximated by interpolating polynomials with abscissas that are transformed Chebyshev polynomial roots/extrema.)

Lastly, whatever you finally settle with, you will want to perform the sanity check of ensuring that all the weights of your quadrature rule are of the same sign; any change of sign in the weights can lead to subtractive cancellation when you employ the quadrature rule, and you wouldn't want that...

Comment: This is without doubt the mathematically correct solution, but, as Robert Israel points out in another answer, it could be the solution to the wrong problem: interpolatory quadrature with badly-chosen nodes can give poor results.

Comment: @Federico: OK, but I see no reason why I cannot combine J.M.'s solution with Robert Israel's point. Given this fact, I am accepting J.M's answer in the other thread, where he provides details, and Robert Israel's answer in this thread, where he provides the warning.